# How to change how much volume the volume key can add or reduce?

Tags: windows-10, audio, keyboard

Windows 10 only allow the volume key to change 2 percents of the volume each time a volume key is pressed. I like to make it 10. Is it possible to modify how much volume keys can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use autohotkey

```
~Volume_Down::SoundSet -8
~Volume_Up::SoundSet +8
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20101101132353/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowspro-audiodevelopment/thread/fa71e319-f1f2-4382-ad69-6a49e534511a).

As you can see, you have to send a HID message for APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP. By default the whole process is bound to 51 steps.

You can use other tools if you want to configure as per your needs. You can found one in [here](https://3rvx.com).

Please note that using other tools is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open source [3RVX program](//github.com/malensek/3RVX):

1. Settings
2. Hotkeys
3. `+`
4. Keys
5. Action: Increase Volume
6. Amount: 10 Percent

Note that 3RVX also has [skins beyond](//github.com/malensek/3RVX/tree/master/Skins) what comes with the release. For
example, I am using the “Windows Default” skin. What is also useful is that you
can customize these skins by modifying the `skin.xml` file. I changed mine to increase the font size.